# how to make a score list and get average using object

Tags: c++

I want to put 100 to score object
and from the object I wanna get average and highest score
but I don't have any idea of the operator

this is class

```
#define MAX_NUM 3

class Score {
int num;
int* score_list;
    public:
    Score() {
        score_list = new int[MAX_NUM];
        num = 0;
    }
    friend Score& operator>>(Score& op,int score);
    friend Score& operator<<(Score& op,float &avg);
    friend int operator ! (Score& op);
    };
```

here are problem. I make the whole codes but

```
Score& operator>>(Score& op, int score) {
(1)
return op;
}

Score& operator<<(Score& op, float& avg) {
int i, sum;

(2)
return op;
}

int operator ! (Score& op) {
int i, max_val;
(3)

}
```

and this is main

```
void main() {
Score s;
int score_list[MAX_NUM] = { 50,60,80 };
float avg;


for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM;i++) {
    s >> score_list[i];
}


s >> 100;  //first, put 100 to the object

s >> avg;
cout << "average = " << avg << endl;  //second get the average from the object


max_score = !s;
cout << "highest score = " << max_score << endl;  //this is for finding hightest score

}
```

Comment: So if I understand this right: `>>` adds a new score to the object, `!` returns the max score. Why do you need to put 100 there? is 100 part of the scores or you use it to indicated the "end of scores"?

Comment: OT: Consider inverting the operators (or use different ones, like += for adding a score), you are "putting" some elements into something and "extracting" the average from the sum of the values.

Comment: @cookiemonster it seems you nuked most of the question!!! is this intentional?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this homework, and if so what part of the code is given and what part you can change yourself. However, the C++ standard library comes with all kinds of functions that make this very easy.

First, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to store scores, instead of a custom class. Then you can use various [algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) to get the data you want out of it. An example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> scores = {50, 60, 80};
    scores.push_back(100);
    auto average = std::accumulate(scores.begin(), scores.end(), 0.f) / scores.size();
    auto highest = *std::max_element(scores.begin(), scores.end());
    std::cout << "average = " << average << "\n";
    std::cout << "highest score = " << highest << "\n";
}
```

If you really want to make a `class Score`, then have it use `std::vector<int>` internally to store scores. Also, instead of overloading operators to get the average and highest score, I would just create regular member functions named `get_average()` and `get_highest()`, because that is much clearer than using `>>` and `!`. In general, only overload operators if you make them do something equivalent to what these operators do on standard types ([principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)).

Comment: rather than casting the result of accumulate, you could use `0.f`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MAX_NUM 3

class Score {
int num;

    public:
    int* score_list;
    Score() {
        score_list = (int*)malloc(MAX_NUM * sizeof(int));
        num = 0;
    }
    friend Score& operator>>(Score& op,int score);
    friend Score& operator<<(Score& op,float &avg);
    friend int operator ! (Score& op);
};
Score& operator>>(Score& op, int score) {
    int size_of_current_array = sizeof(op.score_list) / sizeof(op.score_list[0]);
    
    static int pos = 0;
    if(pos < MAX_NUM){
        op.score_list[pos++] = score;
        op.num++;
    }
        
        
    else{
        op.score_list = (int*)realloc(op.score_list, sizeof(int)*(size_of_current_array + 1));
        op.score_list[pos++] = score;
        op.num++;
    }
        
    return op;
}

Score& operator<<(Score& op, float& avg) {
    int i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < op.num; i++) 
    {
        sum += op.score_list[i];
    }
    avg = sum / op.num;

    return op;
}

int operator ! (Score& op) {
    int i, max_val = op.score_list[0];
    for(i = 0; i < op.num; i++)
    {
        if(max_val < op.score_list[i])
            max_val = op.score_list[i];
    }
    return max_val;
}

int main() {
Score s;
int score_list[MAX_NUM] = { 50,60,80 };
float avg;


for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM;i++) {
    s >> score_list[i];
}



s >> 100;  //first, put 100 to the object

for (int i = 0; i < 4;i++) {
    cout << s.score_list[i] << endl;
}

s << avg;
cout << "average = " << avg << endl;  //second get the average from the object


int max_score = !s;
cout << "highest score = " << max_score << endl;  //this is for finding hightest score

}
```

Comment: Ideally the ```<<``` and ```>>``` are for iostream, and ```!``` for boolean operators